# How to obtain font data to embed in a PDF?

Tags: c++, pdf, winapi, pdf-generation

My MFC application creates a PDF and now I'm trying to embed fonts, the PDF created opens in Foxit, Chrome, and the Windows 8 PDF Reader but doesn't in Acrobat.

I tried validating the pdf file with [this online validator](http://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx) and it says

> The object's identity 6 doesn't match with the object's reference identity 5.
>
> The embedded font program 'Candara' cannot be read.

I think the way I am embedding it's correct

```
3 0 obj
<</Type /Font
    /Subtype /TrueType
    /BaseFont /Candara
    /FirstChar 0
    /LastChar 255
    /Widths 4 0 R
    /FontDescriptor 5 0 R
>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<<
    /Type /FontDescriptor
    /FontName /Candara
    /Flags 32
    /FontBBox [-700 -500 1800 1500]
    /ItalicAngle 0
    /Ascent 12
    /Descent -4
    /CapHeight 8
    /StemV 109
    /FontFile2 6 0 R
>>
endobj

6 0 obj
<<
    /Length 100376
    /Length1 100376
>>
stream
    ... font bytes ...
endstream
endobj
```

I believe my problem it is with the font data which is obtained with

```
LONG ret = ::TTEmbedFont(pDC->GetSafeHdc(),
                    TTEMBED_TTCOMPRESSED, 
                    CHARSET_UNICODE,
                    &ulPrivStatus,
                    &ulStatus,
                    WriteEmbedProc,
                    lpvVecBytes,
                    nullptr,
                    0,
                    0,
                    nullptr);
```

I also tried using **TTEMBED_RAW** and **TTEMBED_EMBEDEUDC**

Sorry for the long and maybe vague explanation but I'm kinda lost,

So **Is this the right way to obtain the font data to embed? If it is, should I applied a filter to the Font file object?**

**EDIT:** I Changed my application to use [GetFontData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd144885(v=vs.85).aspx) which returns the bytes of the font file and according to my research it is ok to use like this, But I still can't open in Acrobat and the online validation site still gives me the same error message.

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4cl25ua05t425h/Teste_.pdf?dl=0) to an example PDF with my issue.

Thanks and any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share an example PDF illustrating the issue?

Comment: @mkl done, but now I believe my problem it's with my PDF object not with the data of the font but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Xpdf is reporting a problem with the xref `Internal Error: xref num 5 not found but needed, try to reconstruct<0a>`

Comment: I think that's what the online validator is trying to tell you as well. The xref has mapped objects 5 & 6 to the same byte offset 1081.

Comment: Also note there's some junk at the end of the contents stream (8 0 R), which ends with `ET
0�4Oendstream
endobj`

Comment: @dwarring YOU ARE A HERO SIR, THANK YOU SO MUCH, I was going crazy with this. THANK YOU

Comment: @dwarring would you make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font emedding itself look ok. There's actually a lower-level error fetching the font objects.

Attempting the view the PDF with Xpdf gives an error with the cross reference table: `xref num 5 not found but needed, try to reconstruct<0a>`.

Looking at the cross reference table at the end of the PDF:

`xref
0 10
0000000000 65535 f 
0000242485 00000 n
0000242426 00000 n
0000000016 00000 n
0000000155 00000 n 
0000001081 00000 n % Wrong should be 0000241738
0000001081 00000 n

0000241929 00000 n 
0000242056 00000 n 
0000242353 00000 n`

The actual error is on line 6 of the cross reference table, which contains the byte offset for object `6 0 R`, instead of `5 0 R`.

The message from the online validator `The object's identity 6 doesn't match with the object's reference identity 5.` is caused by the online validator trying to fetch object `5 0 R` via the index, but actually getting object `6 0 R`.

Cross reference table for this PDF needs to be fixed.